# iOS Box Web API Library Multiple Box accounts

Tags: ios, ios5, ios6, box-api

I am currently working an an app that requires access to multiple Box accounts. I am using the Web API Library. So far, I am successful in accessing a single account. I am saving the auth token when I authenticate a new user. And then when I want to access any account, I use `[Box +initializeSessionWithAuthToken:callbacks:]` with the respective auth token. But I am only redirected back to the login page again. Just before initializing a new session, I use `[Box +logoutWithCallbacks:]` to logout the old user. What Am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you make any progress with this, I was thinking of doing the exact same thing although yet to try.

Comment: The workaround was to write a Box REST wrapper from scratch. The official SDK doesn't seem to support Multiple Logins.

Comment: I suspected this to be the way forward, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question but

```
+logoutWithCallbacks:nil
```

Should invalidate the session and log out the user. Have you verified that this method completed successfully and actually did log out the user.

Then you can use

```
+ (void)initiateWebViewLoginWithCallbacks:(BoxOperationCallbacksDefine)callbacks;
```

or

```
+ (void)initiateLoginUsingURLRedirectWithCallbacks:(BoxOperationCallbacksDefine)callbacks;
```

these will display a new web log in and allow you to create a new authentification token for the new user

Comment: Sorry just trying to help. Accessing multiple box accounts could mean context switching without loosing previously downloaded data or it could mean simultaneous. All do respect multiple and how to approach it can mean many things. A more specific wording would have been useful as well